# Disable CDBS licensecheck step for local builds with "dpkg-buildpackage -b"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, deb, dpkg

I'm doing several huge package builds with `dpkg-buildpackage -b` in Ubuntu 17.04 (Debian-like "stretch/sid"). Packages has very high number of files and in build process there is step `Scanning upstream source for new/changed copyright notices...` with `licensecheck` script to recreate `debian/copyright_newhints`:

```
apt source packagename-V.E.R
sudo apt build-dep packagename-V.E.R
cd packagename-V.E.R

DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS='nostrip noopt debug' dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc -us

... normal work ...

make[1]: Leaving directory '..../debian/build/deb'
touch debian/stamp-makefile-check/deb
CDBS WARNING:  DEB_MAKE_CHECK_TARGET unset, not running checks
 fakeroot debian/rules binary
CDBS WARNING:  copyright-check disabled - touch debian/copyright_hints to enable.
debian/rules:158: warning: overriding recipe for target 'list-missing'
/usr/share/cdbs/1/rules/utils.mk:126: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'list-missing'
test -x debian/rules
dh_testroot
dh_prep -X org.gtk.test.gschema.xml.orig
dh_installdirs -A
mkdir -p "debian/build"
CDBS WARNING:    DEB_DH_INSTALL_ARGS is deprecated since 0.4.85
CDBS WARNING:    DEB_DH_STRIP_ARGS is deprecated since 0.4.85
CDBS WARNING:    DEB_DH_BUILDDEB_ARGS is deprecated since 0.4.85

Scanning upstream source for new/changed copyright notices...

set -e; LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 /usr/bin/licensecheck --check '.*' --recursive --copyright --deb-fmt --ignore '^(debian/(changelog|copyright(|_hints|_newhints)))$' --lines 0 * | /usr/lib/cdbs/licensecheck2dep5 > debian/copyright_newhints
```

The step `licensecheck --check '.*' --recursive` is very slow and takes up to dozen minutes or even longer (and in `top` output `licensecheck` is the program which consumes CPU time). It does something like custom grepping of all files. But I have fast FS and reading all of files (with md5sum computation) is just 10 seconds.

I want to make this step faster: either by disabling licensecheck run completely or by changing some settings of licensecheck to make it faster.

Answer (score 2):

I'm stuck at this issue myself. A quick and dirty workaround is to simply `apt-get remove licensecheck`, and then reinstall after you're done building. It will just say it couldn't find it and continue with the build.

I would post this as a comment, but stackoverflow wants me register for an account.